# How to insert a SVG file in a PDF document?

Tags: python, pdf, svg

I'm trying use [embeddSVG.py](http://jan.kollhof.net/projects/svg/svgpdf/) to embed an SVG in a PDF, but Adobe Acrobat Reader doesn't show svg content in my pdf.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably better off first converting the SVG to PDF.

Apache Batik includes [SVG Rasterizer](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html), which, despite its name, can convert SVG to PDF.

This is used by Apache FOP to convert Docbook documents that include SVG graphics to PDF.

Answer (score 2):

Save the SVG as a PDF, and then open the PDF in Acrobat.

For example, if you create the SVG in Inkscape, then you would go to **File -> Save a copy -> Save as PDF**, and then open it up in Acrobat. This method should preserve text and vector paths.

If you instead choose Print -> Print to File as PDF, then the image will become rasterized (pixelated) and lose its vector powers.

You may also save your SVG image as a DWG file or as an EMF file, both of which are easier formats to open/import into Acrobat than an SVG. (Note to Adobe: "Hey, Adobe, it's time to start supporting direct SVG imports into Acrobat!")

If you are working with SVGs, Inkscape or a similar program (Illustrator or CorelDraw) is essential. Inkscape is free.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [svglib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/svglib)  to convert your svg to pdf and then include it using pyPdf. Note that svglib seems to use reportlab so you can probably use their api to manipulate your file.

Comment: Thank nicoe. But svglib don't help me.
Added svg content is generally displayed in a PDF file?
Maybe someone knows  where i  find for example   pdf with embed svg.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf

156. Beginning with Acrobat 8.1, Acrobat no long provides support for SVG slideshows.Acrobat 5.1 through 8.0 support SVG slideshows (MIME content type image/svg+xml).

Comment: @kmd: could you please give more details on the source of your claim? the pdf ref says, that as of acrobat 5.1 svg is the _only  kind_ of slideshow supported (footnote 156/p.). the specs also contain an example comprisong svg slideshow elements (ex. 9.1 / p. 788/9). best regards, carsten