# Render SVG Tag in PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn

I want to render a signature in a pdf.

my html code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <path stroke="navy" stroke-width="2" fill="none" d="<%= @image %>"/>
</svg>
```

> @image = "M96,8 L96,9 L96,11 L96,14 L98,18 L101,22 L115,32 L126,43
>   L142,50 L165,56 L189,56 L207,56 L219,50 L230,46 L233,43 L235,41
>   L236,40 L238,39 L239,39"

how can I render this in pdf?

im using rails 3 + prawn.

OR how can i create with @image an png?

any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with ruby on rails or prawn but if you look at the Graphics section of the PDF spec, specifically in the path section it shows how the commands are laid out.

You could potentially use this info to map from the SVG draw commands to the postscript/pdf draw commands.

A question that might help: [How to insert a SVG file in a PDF document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360641/how-to-insert-a-svg-file-in-a-pdf-document)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) gem which renders HTML and JavaScript into a PDF file. It uses the `wkhtmltopdf` lib.

To convert to PNG I would recommend the [IMGKit](https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit) gem, which uses `wkhtmltoimage` lib.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/mogest/prawn-svg

Can't confirm if it works, but as I needed to do the same as you.

I've found that after a simple google research I found this plugin.

I will test it as soon as I can.

Kind regards