# How to convert/save d3.js graph to pdf/jpeg

Tags: svg, d3.js, pdf-generation

I'm working on a client-side/javascript function to save or convert an existing D3-SVG graph into a file.
I've searched a lot and found some recommendations, mainly using `canvas.toDataURL()`.

I have no `<canvas>` in my page, and instead using:`d3.select("body").append("svg")....`
I've also tried to append the SVG to the `<canvas>` but nothing happens.

Could you please help me to resolve this exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<SVGSVGElement> has no method 'toDataURL'
```

Thank you

Comment: For in-browser conversion to png, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser

Comment: If it doesn't need to be at runtime, tools like casperjs let you take a screenshot of any element in the page http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper.captureSelector

Comment: For pdf export, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360641/how-to-insert-a-svg-file-in-a-pdf-document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out by @Premasagar in this comment on this question [Convert SVG to image (JPEG, PNG, etc.) in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser#comment28332332_3976034)

If the borwser supports both SVG and canvas you can use this technique https://svgopen.org/2010/papers/62-From_SVG_to_Canvas_and_Back/index.html

```
function importSVG(sourceSVG, targetCanvas) {
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLSerializer
    svg_xml = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(sourceSVG);
    var ctx = targetCanvas.getContext('2d');

    // this is just a JavaScript (HTML) image
    var img = new Image();
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG#Native_support
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.btoa
    img.src = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(svg_xml);

    img.onload = function() {
        // after this, Canvas’ origin-clean is DIRTY
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

To display your svg within a canvas, you first have to convert it using a parser/renderer utility such as http://code.google.com/p/canvg/

(code adapted from: [Convert SVG to image (JPEG, PNG, etc.) in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser), not tested)

```
// the canvg call that takes the svg xml and converts it to a canvas
canvg('canvas', $("#my-svg").html());

// the canvas calls to output a png
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Comment: The first line will not work because 1. canvg awaits for the URL, not the actual XML data and 2. $('svg').html() would not work either - you'll need innerSVG JS library to get access to inner SVG XML.

Comment: `canvg(document.getElementById('drawingArea'), '<svg>...</svg>')` is given as usage https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg. Changed `$('svg').html() `  to `$("#my-svg").html()`.

Comment: Once you have img, how do you trigger a download of it?

Comment: $("#my-svg").html() won't return the opening and closing `<svg>` tags; to get this to work, I had to call `canvg('canvas', "<svg>" + $("my-svg").html() + "</svg>")`.

Comment: this does not seem to work in the browser when I use the npm build.

Answer (score 6):

Just a heads up that I turned this concept into a small JavaScript library: https://github.com/krunkosaurus/simg

It simply converts any SVG to an image to swap out or trigger a download.  Idea taken from here: http://techslides.com/save-svg-as-an-image/

Comment: im trying you js library but is not working. The code from techslides does work, although not in Firefox 33.0

One thing i notice is that your code references the a.href to the img src, instead of the canvas data URL. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, im using a lineChart from DC.js and the png file looks like css styles were not applied, even though i pasted all dc.css in the html.

Comment: @sebastian: Just a heads up that after receiving a few pull request I went ahead and updated the codebase with documentation and more features.

Comment: This throws an error in Chrome as it refuses to deal with MIME

Comment: Working good for me except that `d3.js` produced chart is black and white, colors got lost. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The Simg library created and suggest by Mauvis Ledford above worked great for allowing my svg charts created with Dimple to be downloaded.

I did however need to change one aspect of the code to make it work. Inside of the toString() prototype, inside the forEach loop (line 37), if you change "svg.setAttribute(..)" to "svg[0].setAttribute" it will alleviate the "setAttribute(..) is not a function" error. Similarly the same needs to be done right below in the return statement, appending "[0]" after svg (line 39).

I also had to manually edit the "canvas.width" and "canvas.height" (lines 48 & 49) assignments in the toCanvas() prototype, in order to make the downloaded image a more correct size (it was previously just downloading a static 300x150 square in the top left corner of the chart).

Comment: You are my hero. Now it works. But I had also to append the "[0]" in line 91 and 92 at the `self.svg`. Unfortunately, I only get a black rectangle. Nothing is shown in it.

Comment: Could you give an example please ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, in 2022 we have ES6 and we don't need 3rd party libraries.

Here is a very basic way to convert `svg` images into other formats.

The trick is to load the `svg` element as an `img` element, then use a canvas element to convert into a desired format. So four steps are necessary:

1. Extract `svg` as `xml` data string.
2. Load the `xml` data string into a `img` element
3. Convert the `img` element to a `dataURL` using a `canvas` element
4. Load the converted `dataURL` into a new `img` element

#### Step 1

Extracting a `svg` as `xml` data string is simple:

```js
// Select the element:
const $svg = document.getElementById('svg-container').querySelector('svg')

// Serialize it as xml string:
const svgAsXML = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString($svg)

// Encode it as a data string:
const svgData = `data:image/svg+xml,${encodeURIComponent(svgAsXML)}`
```

#### Step 2

Loading the `xml` data string into a `img` element:

```js
// This function returns a Promise whenever the $img is loaded
const loadImage = async url => {
    const $img = document.createElement('img')
    $img.src = url
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $img.onload = () => resolve($img)
        $img.onerror = reject
        $img.src = url
    })
}
```

#### Step 3

Converting the `img` element to a `dataURL` using a `canvas` element:

```js
const $canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
$canvas.width = $svg.clientWidth
$canvas.height = $svg.clientHeight
$canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, $svg.clientWidth, $svg.clientHeight)
return $canvas.toDataURL(`image/${format}`, 1.0)
```

#### Step 4

Loading the converted `dataURL` into a new `img` element:

```js
const $img = document.createElement('img')
$img.src = dataURL
$holder.appendChild($img)
```

Here you have a working snippet:

```js
const $svg = document.getElementById('svg-container').querySelector('svg')
const $holder = document.getElementById('img-container')
const $label = document.getElementById('img-format')

const destroyChildren = $element => {
  while ($element.firstChild) {
    const $lastChild = $element.lastChild ?? false
    if ($lastChild) $element.removeChild($lastChild)
  }
}

const loadImage = async url => {
  const $img = document.createElement('img')
  $img.src = url
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $img.onload = () => resolve($img)
    $img.onerror = reject
    $img.src = url
  })
}

const convertSVGtoImg = e => {
  const $btn = e.target
  const format = $btn.dataset.format ?? 'png'
  $label.textContent = format

  destroyChildren($holder)

  const svgAsXML = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString($svg)
  const svgData = `data:image/svg+xml,${encodeURIComponent(svgAsXML)}`

  loadImage(svgData).then(img => {
    const $canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    $canvas.width = $svg.clientWidth
    $canvas.height = $svg.clientHeight
    $canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, $svg.clientWidth, $svg.clientHeight)
    return $canvas.toDataURL(`image/${format}`, 1.0)
  }).then(dataURL => {
    console.log(dataURL)
    const $img = document.createElement('img')
    $img.src = dataURL
    $holder.appendChild($img)
  }).catch(console.error)
}

const buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-format]')]
for (const $btn of buttons) {
  $btn.onclick = convertSVGtoImg
}
```

```html
<div style="float: left; width: 70%">
  <div style="float: left; width: 50%">
    <div id="svg-container">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 248 204">
  <path fill="#1d9bf0" d="M221.95 51.29c.15 2.17.15 4.34.15 6.53 0 66.73-50.8 143.69-143.69 143.69v-.04c-27.44.04-54.31-7.82-77.41-22.64 3.99.48 8 .72 12.02.73 22.74.02 44.83-7.61 62.72-21.66-21.61-.41-40.56-14.5-47.18-35.07 7.57 1.46 15.37 1.16 22.8-.87-23.56-4.76-40.51-25.46-40.51-49.5v-.64c7.02 3.91 14.88 6.08 22.92 6.32C11.58 63.31 4.74 33.79 18.14 10.71c25.64 31.55 63.47 50.73 104.08 52.76-4.07-17.54 1.49-35.92 14.61-48.25 20.34-19.12 52.33-18.14 71.45 2.19 11.31-2.23 22.15-6.38 32.07-12.26-3.77 11.69-11.66 21.62-22.2 27.93 10.01-1.18 19.79-3.86 29-7.95-6.78 10.16-15.32 19.01-25.2 26.16z"/>
</svg>
    </div>
    <div>svg</div>
  </div>

  <div style="float: right; width: 50%">
    <div id="img-container"></div>
    <div id="img-format"></div>
  </div>

</div>

<div>
  <button id="btn-png" data-format="png">PNG</button>
  <button id="btn-jpg" data-format="jpeg">JPG</button>
  <button id="btn-webp" data-format="webp">WEBP</button>
</div>
```