# Convert div or svg to datauri

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, c3.js

I have basically created a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9hrux8g0/1/) and made a sample chart.

This is the code for the chart

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        json: [{
            date: '2014-01-01',
            upload: 200,
            download: 200,
            total: 400
        }, {
            date: '2014-01-02',
            upload: 100,
            download: 300,
            total: 400
        }, {
            date: '2014-02-01',
            upload: 300,
            download: 200,
            total: 500
        }, {
            date: '2014-02-02',
            upload: 400,
            download: 100,
            total: 500
        }],
        keys: {
            x: 'date',
            value: ['upload', 'download']
        }
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: function (x) {
                    if (x.getDate() === 1) {
                        return x.toLocaleDateString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I am attempting to convert this chart in to a datauri which i can use to draw an image. I was wondering what is the best way to do this?

I did research and found the following [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049538/how-to-convert-save-d3-js-graph-to-pdf-jpeg) but I am not able to successfully implement it. Any help on this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: You really need to show us your datauri implementation so far so we can see where you're going wrong.

Comment: @RobertLongson answer provided is what i did and as you can see the colors are missing

Comment: There's no code to create a data uri in your fiddle.

Comment: @RobertLongson take a look now

Comment: @RobertLongson the image looks different from original chart for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

For making svg to image, first you need draw it on canvas and then get dataUrl from canvas. 
I edited you're fiddle, seems there are some rendering problems but there are main steps to do that.

```
canvg('canvas', document.getElementById('chart').innerHTML);

// the canvas calls to output a png
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hrux8g0/1/)

Comment: For some reason the image is missing colors

Comment: The problem is only black closing shapes, The colors seems looks ok.

Comment: If you look at the line of x axis and y axis it's much more bold than the original