# convert angular nvd3 chart as pdf/png

Tags: angularjs, charts, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I am using angular nvd3  chart for plotting data on charts. 
I need to export my chart as pdf/png. tried with jdPDF. But It is not rendering css. Can anyone help me out this?

Comment: add the code which you have tried

Comment: nvd3 is wrapper over d3. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049538/how-to-convert-save-d3-js-graph-to-pdf-jpeg

Answer (score 0):

Nvd3 does not come with export functionality. There are three ways which you can do,

(i) Conver the element into SVG, send SVG to Server , convert it to PNG and generate link to download using **[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)**

(ii) Convert SVG to html5 canvas , then convert canvas to PNG and download it
using **[saveSvgAsPng](https://github.com/exupero/saveSvgAsPng)**

**[Example here](http://dixon629.github.io/2015/03/28/svg-to-png/)**

Comment: Although you have said there are 3 ways. Only two are mentioned. I prefer using DigInEngine to do this, which has well optimized codes. https://github.com/DuoSoftware/DigInEngine