# Embedding SVG in Office 365 page

Tags: svg, office365, inkscape

Office 365 newbie. Just want to build a web page. Create a web page. Fine. Try to embed some SVG (from InkScape). Displays resulting image fine (yay!) but when I save, image disappears and says I should have used "embed command". Ok, try embed dialog. Displays resulting image fine (yay!) which then disappears when I save. I would just assume no SVG support, but it seems to be able to draw images from SVG just fine, but tosses the SVG code whenever I save. Hoping there's a checkbox somewhere that says "stop throwing away embedded SVG".

Comment: I see very simple SVG seems to work. Guess it's some particular in the Inkscape output. Will try the export to EMF first.

Comment: Can load InkScape .svg file as "asset" then refer to it via an <img> tag, but then resources referred to not loaded (e.g., text does not appear). No joy with inline or "embed command" use of <object> either.

Comment: And using a raw <embed> tag gives me the error message that I just use "the embed command". Doing *that* and then re-entering the raw <embed> again gets the content removed once again.

Answer (score 0):

When I used Word 2010 and Inkscape, I found it useful to export the image from Inkscape as an Enhanced Metafile (EMF). I did so because the images then remained vectorized in PDFs. Not using Windows anymore, I can't speak for Word 2013, but I'd suggest you try it.

Comment: Ah, yeah, not trying to make a Word document but an HTML page. Can't see any way for EMF to help me there.

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 started to [support SVG](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-SVG-images-in-Microsoft-Office-69f29d39-194a-4072-8c35-dbe5e7ea528c) format recently. Saving an Office file with SVGs in it shouldn't cause any problems anymore.

Btw: If someone needs to export a document to PDF, it is still recommended to use EMF as vector graphic format, since [PDF doesn't support SVG natively](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3360641/5846045).